# How do I "tell" to C compiler that the code shouldn't be optimized out?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-optimization

Sometimes I need some code to be executed by the CPU exactly as I put it in the source. But any C compiler has it's optimization algorithms so I can expect some tricks. For example:

```
unsigned char  flag=0;

interrupt ADC_ISR(){
  ADC_result = ADCH;
  flag = 1;
}

void main(){
  while(!flag);
  echo ADC_result;
}
```

Some compilers will definitely make `while(!flag);` loop infinitive as it will suppose `flag` equals to false (`!flag` is therefore always true).

Sometimes I can use `volatile` keyword. And sometimes it can help. But actually in my case (AVR GCC) `volatile` keyword forces compiler to locate the variable into SRAM instead of registers (which is bad for some reasons). Moreover many articles in the Internet suggesting to use `volatile` keyword with a big care as the result can become unstable (depending on a compiler, its optimization settings, platform and so on).

So I would definitely prefer to somehow point out the source code instruction and tell to the compiler that this code should be compiled exactly as it is. Like this: `volatile while(!flag);`

Is there any standard C instruction to do this?

Comment: Of course a `volatile` variable goes to RAM! Registers are for temporary values, An interrupt can occur anytime. I'd recommend to do some more research about concurrency, especially interrupt handlers and embedded software development. For instance for a boolean flag you should use the boolean standard type.

Comment: Volatile means the variable value can't be cached between reads (and that writes can't be moved around). Yes, that does generally result in offloading into RAM every time. If you think you can do better than that, you should try [inline assembly](http://www.ethernut.de/en/documents/arm-inline-asm.html).

Comment: @Cubic: What change would  inline assembly do for the variables? OP seems not even to think about badly optimised code, but resource usage. The only solution to this would be to write **everything** in Assembler, so he can control CPU register and memory allocation 100%. Micromanagement at its best. I hav done this for many years and am very happy we have compilers which care about this.

Comment: Those articles are right and wrong often at the same time when they warn about `volatile`. Read them with caution and get the basics right. Think for yourself and learn. Most of those articles don't even know about embedded software, but multitasking in general. While there are assues, AVR is on the safe side.

Comment: @Olaf Are you sure that it's about resource usage? I got the impression he simply didn't want the overhead from a ram read. (Although I agree it doesn't _seem_ like a good idea here, I have no idea what exactly OP is trying to do here0.

Comment: @Cubic: Is the CPU not a resource? (FYI: on AVR, RAM reads/writes are not expensive like on x86, etc. with good optimising compiler.) Anyway, as I wrote, there is hardly a way around. A static variable is a static variable and typically never goes into a CPU register.

Comment: There's no such thing as "code compiled exactly as it is".

Comment: @Olaf nevermind, it won't work anyway.

Comment: I have had to use attribute "used" (I forget the attribute syntax) when c interacted with inline assembly that were in the same compilation unit - the compiler knows nothing about what asm does..  It said something like warning foo unused _and_ a linker error - cannot find foo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should indeed use `volatile` as [answered by David Schwartz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39078851/841108). See also [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Volatiles.html#Volatiles) chapter of GCC documentation.

If you use a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler, you could disable optimizations in a single function by using appropriate [function specific options pragmas](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas.html) (or some `optimize` function [attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes)), for instance

```
#pragma GCC optimize ("-O0");
```

before your `main`. I'm not sure it is a good idea.

Perhaps you want [extended `asm` statements with the `volatile` keyword](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Volatile).

Answer (score 8):

The only standard C way is `volatile`. If that doesn't happen to do exactly what you want, you'll need to use something specific for your platform.

Comment: There is no need for something "special".

Answer (score 2):

You have several options:

1. Compile without optimisations. Unlike some compilers, GCC doesn't optimise by default so unless you tell it to optimise, you should get generated code which looks very similar to your C source. Of course you can choose to optimise some C files and not others, using simple make rules.
2. Take the compiler out of the equation and write the relevant functions in assembly. Then you can get exactly the generated code you want.
3. Use volatile, which prevents the compiler from making any assumptions about a certain variable, so for any use of the variable in C the compiler is forced to generate a LOAD or a STORE even if ostensibly unnecessary.